# XPATH exclude a inner tag when extract the full text and recover the original sentences order

Tags: xpath

```
<p>abc</p> 
<p>c<strong>d<\/strong></p>
```

I try to use xpath to extract the full text inside the `p` tag. I use the expression `//div[@id='artibody']/p//text()`, but I can not recover the original sentence order. The result is `['abc', 'c', 'd']`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:  `string-join(//div[@id='artibody']/p//text(), "")`

Returns: abccd

The `//` ignores the child tags, and `string-join` concatenates the results.

If you want to add a joiner string, use the second argument:

`string-join(//div[@id='artibody']/p//text(), "-")`

returns: abc-c-d

See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join) for an explanation.